# Get default value in excel autofilter searchbox

Tags: vba, excel

It is possible to pass a variable to excel autofilter searchbox ? (Except sendkeys method)

```
Sub slixx()
Dim x
x = "bubi"
Range("b10").Select
SendKeys "%{down}"
SendKeys "%{down}e"
SendKeys x
End Sub
```

Thank you.
[image: img here]

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Friendly reminder: StackOverflow is not a "we code for you" service provider. [Introduction to VBA](https://blog.udemy.com/excel-macros-tutorial/)

Comment: hello sgdva. please read again the question, i'm sure you'll get the sense. if not, please notice that i don't ask for code. i just ask if it's possible. can you 'code for me' with '<yes it is possible/>' or '<no, i think that's impossible/>?

Comment: <no, i think that's impossible/> It's not possible to pass a default value to filter objects -as you are trying to do it in the image- other than with the work around send keys method.